# Oracle 12c performance issue

Tags: oracle12c

I have some performance issue when querying on dictionary views. When using RULE hint the query is very fast. What can be the problem ? I have optimizer_mode=RULE in init.ora. Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 with p26635880_121020_Linux-x86-64.zip patch applied

```
SQL> SET TIMING ON;
SQL> 
SQL>             select /*+ RULE */
  2                 *
  3              from
  4                  v$locked_object lo,
  5                  all_objects     ao,
  6                  v$lock          ll
  7              where
  8                  lo.object_id  = ao.object_id
  9              and lo.xidsqn     = ll.id2
 10              and ao.data_object_id  = dbms_rowid.rowid_object('AAAgW6AACAAM7UiAAA');
    XIDUSN    XIDSLOT     XIDSQN  OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID ORACLE_USERNAME                OS_USER_NAME                   PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE     CON_ID OWNER                                                                            OBJECT_NAME                                                                      SUBOBJECT_NAME                                                                    OBJECT_ID DATA_OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE             CREATED     LAST_DDL_TIME TIMESTAMP           STATUS  TEMPORARY GENERATED SECONDARY  NAMESPACE EDITION_NAME                                                                     SHARING       EDITIONABLE ORACLE_MAINTAINED ADDR             KADDR                   SID TYPE        ID1        ID2      LMODE    REQUEST      CTIME      BLOCK     CON_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------ ----------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------- ------------------- ------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------- ----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Executed in 0,766 seconds

SQL> 
SQL>             select
  2                 *
  3              from
  4                  v$locked_object lo,
  5                  all_objects     ao,
  6                  v$lock          ll
  7              where
  8                  lo.object_id  = ao.object_id
  9              and lo.xidsqn     = ll.id2
 10              and ao.data_object_id  = dbms_rowid.rowid_object('AAAgW6AACAAM7UiAAA');

    XIDUSN    XIDSLOT     XIDSQN  OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID ORACLE_USERNAME                OS_USER_NAME                   PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE     CON_ID OWNER                                                                            OBJECT_NAME                                                                      SUBOBJECT_NAME                                                                    OBJECT_ID DATA_OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE             CREATED     LAST_DDL_TIME TIMESTAMP           STATUS  TEMPORARY GENERATED SECONDARY  NAMESPACE EDITION_NAME                                                                     SHARING       EDITIONABLE ORACLE_MAINTAINED ADDR             KADDR                   SID TYPE        ID1        ID2      LMODE    REQUEST      CTIME      BLOCK     CON_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------ ----------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------- ------------------- ------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------- ----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Executed in 83,39 seconds

SQL> 
optimizer_adaptive_plans                                                         TRUE
optimizer_adaptive_statistics                                                    FALSE
db_file_multiblock_read_count                                                    128
optimizer_features_enable                                                        12.1.0.2
optimizer_mode                                                                   RULE
optimizer_index_cost_adj                                                         100
pga_aggregate_target                                                             13474201600
workarea_size_policy                                                             AUTO
optimizer_dynamic_sampling                                                       0
_optimizer_aggr_groupby_elim                                                     FALSE
optimizer_adaptive_reporting_only                                                TRUE
optimizer_adaptive_features                                                      TRUE
_optimizer_reduce_groupby_key                                                    FALSE
13 rows selected
Executed in 0,156 seconds

SQL>
```

Comment: RULE seems to no longer be a valid mode in 12c. It has been deprecated for a while, so it's not surprising.
Can you provide a SQL Monitor report for both versions of the query?

Comment: yes, checked the documentation. I set optimizer_mode  = ALL_ROWS, 12 default value. RULE hint seems to still available in 12c. I'll use it where it's needed. Thanks

Comment: You have not gotten to the root cause. We need to find out why the query is slow without the RULE hint. Again, can you provide SQL Monitor reports?